# XnView how to skip video files when browsing photos

Tags: image-viewer

When clicking next in XnView, it will open image or video (.avi) as long as it support the format. Is there any way to browse photos only and skip video files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tool > Option > Preview > uncheck Auto play for Video/Audio & Show first frame for videos.

Tool > Option > View > Misc. > uncheck Play movie

Comment: Also uncheck the video files in "Options > Browser > File List", else it will show a black screen for video files (though not playing it).

Comment: There is no option submenu in the tools menu, there is only settings. Is this another version than the current XnView??